# Selenium_Select And Item In A "Div"

Tags: java, selenium

Im new on Selenium and stuck on a selection of an item in a "Div", in a "UL", in a "LI", in a "class" ^^"

Here is the page : (i want to click on the "Megaboss") : 
https://www.games-workshop.com/fr-FR/Warhammer?N=403739901+453061871&Nr=AND%28sku.siteId%3AFR_gw%2Cproduct.locale%3Afr_FR_gw%29&Nrs=collection%28%29%2Frecord%5Bproduct.startDate+%3C%3D+1564996500000+and+product.endDate+%3E%3D+1564996500000%5D

And here is my fonction :

```
public void CliquerWarboss() {
      find(By.xpath("//section[@id='mainContent']//a[text()='Megaboss']")).click();
```

}

I tried to select it by `cssSelector` and `id` but doesn't seem to work neither.

Here is the issue message :

```
11:26:37.451 [main] DEBUG n.t.c.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - RELATED ISSUES: 
11:26:37.694 [main] ERROR n.t.c.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Cliquer warboss
11:26:37.695 [main] ERROR n.t.c.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - element click intercepted: Element <a class="test-title-link-prod3140156 product-item__name" data-gtm-productfieldobject="{&quot;quantity&quot;:1,&quot;price&quot;:&quot;34.00&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Ironjawz Orruk ...&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;99070209003&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:5,&quot;category&quot;:&quot;GW: Age of Sigmar&quot;}" data-gtm-actionfieldobject="{&quot;list&quot;:&quot;ResultsList | searchResults - Grand Alliance Destruction - Ironjawz&quot;}" href="/fr-FR/Ironjawz-Orruk-Megaboss">Megaboss</a> is not clickable at point (844, 640). Other element would receive the click: <img class="test-img-prod3140157" alt="Warchanter" src="https://www.games-workshop.com/resources/catalog/product/600x620/99070209004_Warchanter01.jpg">
11:26:37.717 [main] DEBUG n.t.core.reports.ReportService - Reporting formats: [JSON, HTML]
```

If anyone could help me to understand what's happend ? :/

thank you

Comment: Hardcoded xpath to that event is (obtained via Chrome inspect option): /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[2]/div[3]/ul/li[5]/a[1].

If you want image it will extend by /img.

As far as I can tell you just not gotten deep enough

Answer (score 0):

To make sure these elements can be clicked on, use the `WebDriverWait`.

```
WebDriverWait waitElmt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = waitElmt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//section[@id='mainContent']//a[text()='Megaboss']")));
element.click();
```